# Python- Finding longest sequence from fasta file?

Tags: python

I need to make a program that prints out the name and length of the longest sequence in a fasta file.

(Note: this is an example file, I need to make a program that works for any number of sequences in a fasta file)

[Here's the fasta file I'm working with (I named it 'fasta.txt')](http://www.pastebin.ca/2985638)

So I'm still a beginner with python, so I don't know many tricks to opening files and such.

I was going to treat this as a regular text file, opening it and turning it into a list. I messed around with how I could get the length of the first sequence and such, but I don't know how I could get the lengths of the other sequences and compare them effectively.

```
file = open('fasta.txt','r')
file = file.read().split('\n')
```

Could anyone help me get started? I just can't get a foothold on this problem. Again, I'm a beginner, and previous google attempts pointed towards using 'biopython' which I've never learned in class, so i'd like something a bit simpler.

Anything that could help me get started would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't all the sequence be adjusted in one line, I mean like, can't the sequence 1 be represented in one line instead of 6-7 lines ?, is that a result of text warping or you have the same exact format of your file ?  have you created this file by yourself or this is an already created file ?

Comment: You really should give Biopython a try. Here's come content to get you started: https://github.com/peterjc/biopython_workshop/blob/master/reading_sequence_files/README.rst

Comment: The text file is how I recieved it.

Comment: Do any of the answers below answer your question? You should accept one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use regexp to split your sequences as follow.

```
import re

F=open('fasta.txt','r')

re_seq=re.compile('>GNOM\s(\d+)\ssequence\s(\d+)\n((?:\w*\n)*)')

numlist=[]
lenlist=[]

for occurence in re_seq.finditer(F.read()):
    gnom,num,seq=occurence.groups()
    numlist.append(num)
    lenlist.append(len(seq))
    print gnom,num,len(seq)

maxl=max(lenlist)

print "max length :",maxl

for num,length in zip(numlist,lenlist):
   if length==maxl:
      maxnum=num

print "max number :",maxnum
```

This give me, from an extract of your file :

373 1 538
373 2 606
373 3 743
max length : 743
max number : 3

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('fasta.txt','r')
current_string=""
current_name =""
max = -1000
for line in file:
    if line.startswith(">GNOM"):
        #last sequence ended:
        if len(current_string) > max :
            max = len(current_string)
            max_name = current_name

        #start reading a new sequence:
        current_name = line
        current_string=""
    else:
        current_string+=line.strip("\n")
print max_name, max
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Thomas' comment; there's no need to reinvent the wheel. Here's how to do it with BioPython: Start by running 'pip install biopython' in a terminal.

```
from Bio import SeqIO


max_len = 0
max_description = ""

for record in SeqIO.parse('fasta.txt', "fasta"):
    if len(record) > max_len:
        max_len = len(record)
        max_description = record.description

print(max_description)
print(max_len)
```

This prints:

```
GNOM 373 sequence 15
775
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar with [Turtles Are Cute](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225444/turtles-are-cute) by Biopython but uses `Bio.SeqIO.to_dict()`, and sorts the fasta by sequence length:

```
# Finding_longest_sequence_from_fasta_file.py
from Bio import SeqIO

with open("fasta.txt", "rU") as handle:
    record_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"))

for id in sorted(record_dict, key=lambda id: len(record_dict[id].seq), reverse=True):
    print id, len(record_dict[id].seq)
    print record_dict[id].format("fasta")
    break
```

The link to `fasta.txt` doesn't work anymore, so here with my example:

`$ cat fasta.txt`

```
>A
ATCGGTCGAA
>B
ATGGTCTACATAGCTGACAAACAGCACGTAGCAATCGGTCGAATCTCGAGAGGCATATGGTCACATGATCGGTCGAGCGTGTTTCAAAGTTTGCGCCTAG
>C
ATCGGTCGAGCGTGT
```

`$ python Finding_longest_sequence_from_fasta_file.py`

```
B 100
>B
ATGGTCTACATAGCTGACAAACAGCACGTAGCAATCGGTCGAATCTCGAGAGGCATATGG
TCACATGATCGGTCGAGCGTGTTTCAAAGTTTGCGCCTAG
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy!

```
#In python 2.7
reading = open('fasta.txt', 'r').readlines()
length = 0
index_seq = 0
for index, line in enumerate(reading):
    if not line.startswith('>'):
        if len(line) > result:
            result = len(line)
            index_seq = index
print reading[index_seq-1] #This give you the name of the sequence
print reading[index]       #This give you the sequence
print result               #This give you the length of the sequence
```